# Is there a built-in function in C++ Builder/Delphi to save the layout of a form when closed and restore it when opened?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

If I have a form with a `TTreeView` a `TDBGrid` and a `TSpliter`, is there a built-in function to save/load the layout (window size, view sizes on split, the individual field widths of the `TDBGrid`) so that when a user closes a form or program and opens it again, it is put back the way it was?  If so, what is the built-in method?

TIA!!

Comment: There is almost an infinite number of ways to make a form. Most controls are in a static position, and this information is stored in the .dfm and compiled into the exe. For controls that do change, you can write your own code, to save the current position and then restore it when the form is opened again.

Comment: There are 3rd party components available doing what you are looking for.

Comment: The JVCL has got a TFormStorage component that lets you  save/restore a form size, position and also any published property of any control on the form. You need to specify those properties though, it's not automatic. The Values are written to the Registry or to an ini file. Personally I don't use that component (any more), I prefer to write some code because that gives me more control over what is stored, how it stored and where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such built in method.